# Why do I need to compile ffmpeg only directly on PC on which I will develop application which will use ffmpeg libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, video, compilation, ffmpeg

I am going to develop an application which will use ffmpeg library on my PC under Windows 8 on it. I am also going to develop my program with using Visual Studio. I have read [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1309) that to use ffmpeg as a library in my project I need compile ffmpeg at first.

The compilation ffmpeg on OS Windows is really not very easy. **And I want to know why it is impossible to compile ffmpeg on Windows at once and then use this build on any computer running OS Windows?** Why we cant do this?
May be someone can give me all that *.lib files that were created after compiling ffmpeg on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago, I've provided example [how-to use ffmpeg with Microsoft Visual Studio and cmake](https://github.com/snikulov/ffmpeg_win_example).

Requirements:

- shared + dev packages from [zeranoe ffmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/download/)
- Visual Studio from Microsoft

HTH.

Comment: Sergey, thank you for the answer! I'll try to build ffmpeg according to yours tutorial, because i have no luck while building ffmpeg using MinGW. But I wonder why it is impossible to compile ffmpeg only once, then upload the compiled libraries on ffmpeg.org (for example)  and then anybody can download these libraries and add them to project without compilation. Why i need to compile ffmpeg anyway?

Comment: Because the ffmpeg website maintainers are afraid of being sued for distributing software that violates patents.

Comment: @bukka.wh You don't need compile it. Download libraries from  http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ and use.

Comment: njahnke: Thank you! It was really very interesting for me to know the reason for this. I thought that the case in  hardware limitations.

Comment: Sergey: So i just need to download Zeranoe FFmpeg dev build, and then include all *.lib files into my VS project and use them?

Comment: 2 Sergey I have downloaded dev build from ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds, then added all stuff to my project, and now everything works fine! Thank you!